# Is the /dev directory the only place in Linux where device files can be stored?

Tags: linux

I know that the `/dev` directory stores device files, but is the `/dev` directory the only place where device files can be stored, or is it just a convention to store device files in the `/dev` directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just convention.  Indeed, in a `chroot` environment or a container (eg docker) then device entries may be present elsewhere.

What makes a device entry a device entry is the *type* of entry, not it's name

So, for example:

```
% ls -ld /dev/vda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 0 May 26 07:00 /dev/vda
```

The first "b" means this is a block device.  The "253" is the major device number, and the "0" is the minor device number.  In this case

```
% grep virt /proc/devices
253 virtblk
```

So major device 253 is related to the virtual block layer.

You'll note the name "vda" isn't important, here!

I do could

```
sudo mknod /tmp/foo b 253 0
```

Now `/tmp/foo` will access exactly the same data:

```
% sudo dd if=/dev/vda bs=256b count=1 | sum
....
40545   128

% sudo dd if=/tmp/foo bs=256b count=1 | sum
....
40545   128
```

Common names are important for humans and config files (eg `/dev/tty1` is the common name for the first virtual console on a Linux machine; `/dev/ttyS0` is the common name for the first serial port), but it's the type (block/char) and major/minor number that makes it work.

Comment: As a small addition to this answer I'd like to mention the existence of `nodev` mount option which can be used to disable storing of device nodes on a given filesystem.